# can't share hyperlink to whatsapp using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, ios9, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller

I was trying to share some text with a hyperlink using `UIActivityViewController`in my app, the text is formatted using `<html>` script as shown.

```
 UIActivityViewController *activityVC  [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"<html><body><b>This is a bold string</b><br\\>Check out this amazing site: <a href='http://apple.com'>Apple</a></body></html>"] applicationActivities:nil];
```

it shows fine in many social media apps, while it is not working for whatsapp. In whatsapp it shows simply as a plain text (check image attached),

[image: for gmail app]
<------**for gmail app**
[image: for whatsapp app]
<------**for whatsapp app**

what is the issue here? please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Whatsapp support only text so I doubt that it won't be possible to show hyperlink in WhatsApp

Answer (score 1):

May be whatsapp messenger do not support it. As mentioned on this link.  https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

```
WhatsApp Messenger can handle various types of media:

images of any type that conforms to public.image (for example, PNG and JPEG)
videos of any type that conforms to public.movie (for example, MPEG-4 video)
audio files (only MPEG-3, MPEG-4, AIFF, AIFF-C and Core Audio)
```

Comment: This is not the issue here.